# Java, working with files

Tags: java, string, file

I have a text file

```
category1 1 10 101 1 good1
category6 2 11 105 2 good5
category1 5 13 103 3 good4
category3 6 14 102 4 good2
category5 3 12 107 2 good1
```

How do I read the 5-th column ? I need to find the sum of elements in it, but i don't know how to read it. Here is what I've done:

```
    int sum = 0;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Data.txt"));
    String line = br.readLine();
    String[] columns = line.split(" ");
    String[] items = columns[4].split(" ");
    for(int i = 0; i<items.length; i++){
        sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(items[i]);
    }
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: You need to be more specific than 'doesn't work'.

Answer (score 6):

You are only reading the first line of the file. Use:

```
int sum = 0;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Data.txt"));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    String[] columns = line.split(" ");
    sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(columns[4]);        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int sum = 0;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Data.txt"));
String line = "";
while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
String[] columns = line.split(" ");


    sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(columns[4]);
}
```